# Bar graph background

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a bar graph as shown in the attached image.

[image]

When I did my trial in jsfiddle, I am not able to  get the grey bar background: which is the maximum of the y-axis.
How can I achieve this?

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: ' ',
            pointWidth : 28,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }]
    });
});
```

Note - Ultimately, this is a part from an Angularjs project.
Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by having a fake series with all the y values as max y value. keep your yMax as max series value of y. have a look [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9hs4xaa/1/)

you may need tto further do some customization on it like hide tooltip and legend for fake series.

```
 series: [{
        name: ' ',
        pointWidth : 28,   dataLabels: {
                enabled: false 

            }, color:'#bdbdbd',
        data: [216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4, 216.4]

    },{
        name: ' ',         
        pointWidth : 28,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }]
```